# Writing a sub routine in assembly that replaces with 0 the elements of a sequence with absolute value bigger than a positive value X

Tags: assembly, arm64

I have to write a sub-routine in assembly that replaces with 0 the elements of a sequence with absolute value bigger than a positive value X, returning the number of modified elements but I don't know how to start. Can someone help?

So I actually developed a code and we have an input to test if it works well. The input is {7, -8, -23, 56, 20, -10, 0, 40}, being that the output should be that 3 elements were modified  but when I run it, my output says that only 2 were modified even tho when i read the result vector i get {7, -8, 0, 0, 20, -10, 0, 0}, meaning that 3 were actually modified.

- input:  `{7, -8, -23, 56, 20, -10, 0, 40}`
- output: `{7, -8, 0,   0, 20, -10, 0, 0}`, count=2 (actual)
- output (desired): {unknown, X not specified}, count=3

Here is the assembly code I developed:

```
CheckABS:
        MOV W4, #0
        CBZ W1, FIM


Ciclo:  LDR W3, [X2], 4
        CMP W3, W0 //bigger than superior limit?
        B.GT NOK
        CMN W3, W0 //lower than inferior limit?
        B.LT NOK
        B OK

NOK:
        STR XZR, [X2, -4]
        ADD W4, W4, 1
OK:
        SUBS W1, W1, 1
        B.NE Ciclo

FIM:    MOV W0, W4
        ret
```

Comment: assuming 32-bit floating-point elements for x86-64, abs is just clearing the MSB with `andps`, and you can `cmpltps` to get a compare vector.  `andps` with that SIMD compare result will zero elements of the original vector, which you store back to memory.  To count replacements, you can `psubd xmm5, xmm0` to accumulate counts `count -= -1` or `0`, and hsum it at the end.  Or the same idea works as easily for integer with SSSE3 `pabsd` and `pcmpgtd`.  If x86 SSE2 instructions wasn't how you wanted to write this, [edit] your question with details on what ISA, and an attempt.

Comment: Start with something that already works, even if it doesn't do what you want.  For example, find a min or max or sum, working over an array/sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is evidently an array of 32-bit words (`int`), but `STR XZR, [X2, -4]` is a 64-bit store because you're using the 64-bit register `XZR`.  Thus it not only overwrites the 32-bit word you wanted to replace with 0, but also the following one.  I think you instead want `STR WZR, [X2, -4]`.